# How to design a database structure for a table with user set columns

Tags: postgresql, database-design

### TLDR

Is there some database mechanism or design pattern that allows the representation and use of custom columns in a table?

### Longer version

This question has probably been asked before but the word "table" trips search engines up.
I need alternatives for a database design where a user sees a table with mostly custom columns.

Currently Postgresql is used, if there's an alternative engine that performs well with this task, that information would be appreciated.

It would look something like this:

```
  predefined column  | user column1  | user column2  | user column3  | user column4 
 --------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|-------------- 
                  0  |            1  |            2  |            3  |            4 
                  1  |            5  |            6  |            7  |            8
```

And here's the current database structure:

[image]

If the picture doesn't load/ you want to play around here's the SQL for it

```
CREATE SEQUENCE user_table_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE available_column_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE table_column_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE table_row_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
CREATE TABLE user_table (id INT NOT NULL, user_id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE available_column (id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE table_column (id INT NOT NULL, user_table_id INT NOT NULL, column_id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE table_row (id INT NOT NULL, table_column_id INT NOT NULL, user_column INT NOT NULL, predefined_column INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE INDEX IDX_35DE8775E3087FAA ON user_table (user_id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_35DE8775E3087FAB ON table_column (user_table_id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_35DE8775E3087FAC ON table_column (column_id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_35DE8775E3087FAD ON table_row (table_column_id);
ALTER TABLE table_column ADD CONSTRAINT IDX_35DE8775E3087FAE FOREIGN KEY (user_table_id) REFERENCES "user_table" (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
ALTER TABLE table_column ADD CONSTRAINT IDX_35DE8775E3087FAF FOREIGN KEY (column_id) REFERENCES "available_column" (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
ALTER TABLE table_row ADD CONSTRAINT IDX_35DE8775E3087FBA FOREIGN KEY (table_column_id) REFERENCES "table_column" (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
```

There are 2 main problems with this structure:

1. Data integrity is not properly enforced. One column can have 50 table_rows attached, while another has only 1. This is solvable in application layer, however.
2. Working with data seems pretty difficult: things like row count or pagination are hard to obtain. Group by clauses quickly cause headaches with indexes and performance.

I'm hoping that there's some mechanism or design pattern that i don't know, that allows for performant use of a table with custom colums. Extra points if it solves the problem of data integrity too.

One simple thing that could be done is flipping the relation, where table_row references user_table and table_column references table_row. That way row count is easier, but getting all the columns of a specific table is made hard.

Comment: You should not allow the user to modify the table design. Instead you could use a table like this: `property_table(id, property_name, property_value)`

Comment: I would use a single JSONB column that stores the "user defined values" as key/values pairs. You could use a "json schema" to validate the JSON structure, using something like this: https://github.com/gavinwahl/postgres-json-schema

Comment: `Working with data seems pretty difficult` - that is why the database schema/structure should be static rather then dynamically defined by the user. When you need/want to store non-relational data you should consider NoSQL.